# Differential loading script references in index.html different when running ng serve vs. ng build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular8

After upgrading to Angular 8, `ng build` generates a proper index.html that supports differential loading however `ng serve` generates a different index.html that contains references to only some of the generated 'es5' scripts. As a result, the app does not work in ES5 browsers like IE 11.

So far I have:

- confirmed the app runs as expected in modern ES2015+ browsers like Chrome
- confirmed the app worked on IE 11 prior to the Angular 8 upgrade
- compared index.html source in IE 11 to source generated in dist directory from `ng build`, can see differences in script references (see sample code below)
- searched angular and angular-cli issues on Github and stackoverflow for similar problems
- tried building and serving with and without the soon to be deprecated es5BrowserSupport option in angular.json
- updated to the latest versions of @angular-devkit and @angular packages

The repository I am working on contains an application project and a library project. Here are the relevant architect targets from angular.json after the Angular 8 upgrade:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng-shared-components-tester",
            "index": "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/abc-emerald-standards/dist/emerald/assets/css/default.css",
              "node_modules/abc-emerald-standards/dist/emerald/assets/css/forms.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/ng-shared-components-tester/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng-shared-components-tester:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng-shared-components-tester:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

Here is the browserlist file with IE 11 support enabled:

```
> 0.5%
last 4 versions
IE 11
not dead
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "@abc/ng-shared-components": [
        "dist/abc/ng-shared-components"
      ],
      "@abc/ng-shared-components/*": [
        "dist/abc/ng-shared-components/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
}
```

## Expected Result

`ng build` is generated the expected result in dist/ng-shared-components-tester/index.html:

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule></script>
</body>
```

## Actual Result

`ng serve` is serving up an index.html to IE 11 that only contains the ES5 version of pollfills.js:

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
  <script src="polyfills.js"></script><script src="styles.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

After a little more digging I found this [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768) that indicates differential loading is disabled by default for `ng serve` and `ng build --watch` by design. This appears to be done for performance reasons (differential loading requires 2 builds to run, ES5 and non-ES5). There is a workaround to use ES5 bundles instead of the default bundles.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behavior of your code .Angular CLi will detect the browser and inject the polyfill script at the runtime like this

[image]

So if you are using older browser version you will the script that have nomodule tag

You can read it more [here](https://dev.to/lacolaco/differential-loading-a-new-feature-of-angular-cli-v8-4jl)

Comment: I agree that polyfills-es5.js with a nomodule tag is correct behavior. However, what about runtime-es5.js, styles-es5.js, vendor-es5.js and main-es5.js?


When the app loads in the browser, it is failing because these scripts contain ES2015+ code (ex. classes) that won't work in IE 11. I was expecting es5 versions of these scripts to be injected into index.html as well when using using `ng serve` just like `ng build`.

Comment: Can you add your tsconfig please